# node-hbsfy not compiling templates with Gulp

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I'm simply trying to compile hbs templates via Browserify and Gulp, but the compilation process fails as soon as any HTML markup is encountered from my hbs file.

I've confirmed this by removing the HTML code within the hbs file, at which point Browserify runs as expected.

Here is a simplified version of my Gulp task:

```js
const _gulp = require('gulp');
const _browserify = require('browserify');
const _remapify = require('remapify');
const _hbsfy = require('hbsfy');
const _vinylSourceStream = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const _vinylBuffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

_gulp.task('js:dev', () => {
  return _browserify({entries: './src/js/app.js', debug: true})
    .plugin(_remapify, [
      {
        src: '**/*.hbs', // glob for the files to remap
        cwd: './src/markup/components',
        expose: 'components' // this will expose './src/markup/components' as 'components'
      }
    ])
    .transform(_hbsfy)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(_vinylSourceStream('app.js'))
    .pipe(_vinylBuffer())
    .pipe(_gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

The hbs template:

```html
<div class="menu"> </div>
```

The main JS file:

```js
(function (){
  const _handlebars = require('hbsfy/runtime');

  function init () {
    _handlebars.registerPartial('menu', require('components/menu.hbs'));
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
})();
```

What could be going wrong? It's as if the hbsfy transform isn't running properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this issue is actually caused by the [remapify](https://github.com/joeybaker/remapify) plugin. Compilation works as expected using [pathmodify](https://github.com/jmm/pathmodify) instead.

Here is my updated Gulp file:

```
const _gulp = require('gulp');
const _browserify = require('browserify');
const _pathmodify = require('pathmodify');
const _hbsfy = require('hbsfy');
const _vinylSourceStream = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const _vinylBuffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

_gulp.task('js:dev', () => {
  return _browserify({entries: './src/js/app.js', debug: true})
    .plugin(_pathmodify, {
      mods: [
        _pathmodify.mod.dir('components', process.cwd() + '/src/markup/partials/components')
      ]
    })
    .transform(_hbsfy)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(_vinylSourceStream('app.js'))
    .pipe(_vinylBuffer())
    .pipe(_gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```